# isomorphic fundamental groups of quotient space

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I have a set $X\subset \mathbb R^n$  an equivalence relation $x∼-x$.
Say $Y\cong X$ i.e they are homeomorphic. I would like to conclude $\pi_1(X/∼)=\pi_1(Y/∼)$.

Is that true? It does look reasonable.
problem is that as far as I know continuous maps only give homomorphism of fundamental groups.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have any precision on your equivalence relation ? For example, assume $X \cap Y = \emptyset$ and $\pi_1(Y)$ is not trivial. 
Consider the relation $\sim : a \sim b \Leftrightarrow a \in X, b \in X$. 
Then we have $\pi_1(X/\sim) = \{0\}$ and $\pi_1(Y/\sim) \cong \pi_1(Y)$. 
But maybe I misunderstood the question ...

Comment: @N.H.:  for some reason the ∼ didn't print in my original post. I edited it to be clear

Comment: Oh sorry ! Are $[0,1] \cup [-2,-1]$ and $[-10,-9] \cup [-8,-7]$ working for a counter-example ?

Comment: @user2715119: think of $S^n$ which is not convex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the sphere $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ and a "translated sphere" $Y = \{x + 1 \mid x \in \mathbb S^{n-1}\}$. 
We have $(Y/\sim) \cong Y$ and $\mathbb (S^{n-1}/\sim) \cong \mathbb R \mathbb P^{n-1}$ which has different fundamental group than $Y$.

Comment: here $1 = (1, \dots, 1)$

Comment: Thanks. So the main problem is the symmetric? If you gave the example of $S^{n-1}$, lets talk for a second about something I can imagine - $S^2$. and $Y=$the cylinder $S^1 \times [-1,1]$. or maybe take away the north and south ends for it to be actually homemorphic. In that case my result is true?

Comment: Here is the problem is that if you take a bounded space $X$ centred in zero and a second space $X + M$, enought translated, the first one will be modified by $\sim$ and the second one not.

Comment: Here it's working, I think both space are homeomorphic to $\mathbb R \mathbb P^2$. Intuitively, because you have a "symmetric" homeomorphic around zero.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand. A semi-related question: What would be $\pi_1 (S^1/∼)$?

Comment: $(S^1 / \sim) \cong S^1$ and then $\pi_1(S^1/ \sim) \cong \mathbb Z$. But if $n>1$ we have $\pi_1(S^n/\sim) \cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Are you sure? Why (S1/∼)≅S1? That seems wierd

Comment: It's not, you can make a picture. For example, since we have still one representant of each point of $S^1$ in $A = \{(x,y) \in S^1 \mid x \geq 0 \}$ then it follows $A/\sim \cong S^1/\sim$. But $A/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ where you glue $0$ and $1$ together.

Comment: I think that it isn't correct, because [(0,1)] doesn't have a unique representant

Comment: You can look at the wikipedia argument : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_line
(Sorry, I deleted my previous answer because I think it was false, probably a bit too general)